# google.appengine.ext Python Module ImportError No module named google.appengine.ext

Tags: google-api-python-client

Python 2.7.6, Google APIs Client Library for Python for Google App Engine, [Google Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine)

I'm going through the Google documentation, and trying to duplicate their example.  When I run the command:

`from google.appengine.ext import webapp`

from Python Shell, I get the error msg:

`No module named google.appengine.ext`

So obviously, that file is not on my computer.  I've done searches for the file on my hard drive and haven't found anything.  I've run easy_install to install the Google API as instructed in the official Google Quick Start video.  I'm not sure if Google's documentation is now outdated, or what is happening.  Where do I get the google.appengine.ext?  I'm assuming that my problem is simply that I don't have that module.

Comment: Please see my answer here:
["GAE Running Locally"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195967/google-app-engine-error-when-running-dev-appserver-py-no-module-named-appeng/38196084#38196084 )

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add the following line, incase you are running stand alone tests

```
 sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/')
 sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib/')
 if 'google' in sys.modules:
     del sys.modules['google']
```

Comment: This solution don't work for my. I'm trying `from google.appengine.ext import ndb` without dev_server and I don't find why. Any idea?

Comment: Just edited my answer (added sys.modules['google']). Try this

Comment: I Just try this, and doesn't work for me. Maybe I have other problems, I only want try the Google Datastore without the devserver runnig.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen @varun answer in other question, and he use `insert` instead of `append`, and then this work perfectly, at least for me.

```
sys.path.insert(1, '<yourFolder>/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '<yourFolder>/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
if 'google' in sys.modules:           
    del sys.modules['google']
```

Answer (score 2):

App Engine samples presume that you have the App Engine SDK installed:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine

Comment: Thank you.  I'd actually downloaded and installed both of those, plus  google-api-python-client-gae-N.M.zip  And I've found the files that I think are needed.  I'm guessing that the problem is the `PATH` defined on my operating system isn't pointing to those folders, so when I'm running a line of Python code in Python Shell from the folder C:\Python27 the `IMPORT` command is not finding that appengine module.  It looks like I have the appengine SDK files in the `PROGRAM FILES\GOOGLE\GOOGLE_APPENGINE\LIB\GOOGLE-API-PHTHON-CLIENT\OATH2CLIENT`  folder.  I'm guessing that got set up with Launcher.

Comment: For App Engine you need to run your code within the development web server: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver. Once that's running you can use the interactive console provided: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Interactive_Console

Comment: I have used App Engine Launcher, which has a `BROWSE` button that opens my app in my web brower at `http://localhost:8080/`.  I'm assuming that is the same as running the command line: `dev_appserver.py myapp`

Comment: @JoeGregorio PLEASE make this the answer!! I spent 4 hours looking for this.... the sample code makes it look like the SDK auto installs a bunch of modules you can just test and use normally!!

Answer (score -2):

The google.appengine.ext means google/appengine/ext it is just like the packages directory in Eclipse