# Google App Engine - Error when running dev_appserver.py - No module named appengine.api

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

After trying to get Google App Engine working locally, I think it's best to ask this question here, and answer it myself. I'm sure some of you might be having this problem.

After installing the GAE SDK for Python, I tried running the tutorial. I cloned their 'Hello World' app from GitHub, and tried to run it locally using dev_appserver.py. I kept getting an error message saying "No module named appengine.api"

I use TensorFlow, and a few packages developed by Google, and found a way to get around this. I will answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What happened to me was there were a few libraries developed by Google already added to my PYTHONPATH. So when dev_appserver.py was trying execute the following line,

```
from google.appengine.api import appinfo
```

it was throwing an error saying "ImportError: No module named appengine.api" because it was already looking at a different google module. In my case this was caused by Protobuf. I tried to figure out a way to keep Protobuf but the time got to me, and I didn't want to waste any more time. You can run

```
pip list
```

and see whether you have this module installed. What I did was then uninstall it using

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
```

This uninstalls the already added packages to the PYTHONPATH, namely

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/
```

Which is the Google path that created the issue. Now, to be safe, if you run

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine"
```

it should take care of the dev_appserver.py import modules and it should run.

Please comment, or let me know if you figure out a new way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the issue was fixed in SDK version 1.9.40.

This is likely caused by [GAE Issue 12963](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963), which still affects the current (1.9.38) SDK version. See ["ImportError: No module named webapp2" after Linux SDK upgrade (1.9.35 -> 1.9.38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38)

If your SDK version is 1.9.37 or 1.9.38 downgrade to 1.9.36, which you can find [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured). At least until the fix gets released. This allows you to not manually fiddle with the PYTHONPATH which *might* cause you trouble down the road.